# XSLT: Check if variable exits, was declared

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to check if a variable is declared, because there were different .xsl documents included with different variables and I need to check if the variable was declared so I can use it in my process?

I always get an Error with my Process. 
Message: Variable sortedNumbers has not been declared (or its declaration is not in scope)

I use XSLT 2.0

My XSLT Code:

```
<xsl:if test="exists($sortedNumbers) and $sortedNumbers = 'true' >
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to check that with XSLT 2.0. In XSLT 3.0 there is an `xsl:try/xsl:catch` but I am not sure it would help, Saxon seems to signal a static error nevertheless for the undeclared variable, only Exselt seems to use the `xsl:catch`.

Comment: Ok that has be the problem that I can't debug the my .XSL document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-think your approach. If you have a stylesheet A that sometimes imports B and sometimes imports C, then you are doing things the wrong way round: the special-purpose stylesheet module should import the general-purpose module.

Comment: I have different start XSL(StartA,StartB). Both creates different variables. And then both includes the same .xsl

And now I need to check if a specific Variable was created or not.

Comment: Then you should declare the variable as an xsl:param in the included .xsl, which the start XSL may or may not override with a global xsl:variable.